# ASP .NET MVC displayed duplicated rows when joining between 2 tables. How not to?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 table, `student` and `teacher` as shown in the picture below. When I use the code as shown in the controller below, I don't understand why it displays/show 3 data instead of one since I'm selecting only `teacher` table. How do I display as such?

**Table**

[image]

**View Page**

[image]

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult HobbyList()
{
    var query = from t in db.teacher
                join s in db.student on t.hobby equals s.hobby
                select t;

    var result = query.ToList();
    return View(result);
}
```

**View**

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr class='green'>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Hobby</th>
        <th><center>Actions</center></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>@item.hobby</td>
            <td>edit | delete</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: you aren't selecting only the teacher table though, are you, you're joining to student as well. You might decide only to _display_ things from the teacher table, but the underlying query joins all the rows from student as well

Comment: well in my query, im using `select t;` isnt it selecting `teacher` table only?

Comment: I'll repeat: "You might decide only to **display** things from the teacher table, but the **underlying query** joins all the matching rows from student as well ". If you don't want that, and you just want a list of teachers and their hobbies, then lose the join to student. It doesn't seem to have any purpose in this scenario, unless you wish to exclude teachers whose hobbies don't match with any students? Right now your actual query returns the 1 teacher who matches to 3 students with the hobby "aaa". Since you JOINed them, it reports all the matching rows in both tables.

Comment: If you don't understand this I suggest you study the concept of a SQL INNER JOIN in more detail.

Comment: this is because I need to display a list which `teacher` table and `student` table have the same hobby but only wanted to show only teacher row

Comment: try a DISTINCT query in that case

Comment: i tried `var result = query.Distinct();`but i got `The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.` error

Comment: well I don't know the exact linq syntax tbh but the native SQL equivalent would be `SELECT DISTINCT teacher.id, teacher.name, teacher.hobby FROM teacher INNER JOIN student on student.hobby = teacher.hobby`, I guess you can look up how to express that in the linq syntax, or maybe someone else will know

Comment: When you join your teachers and students what you are really doing is asking "what _combinations_ of teachers and students have the same hobby?".  Well, there are 3 combinations, teacher 1 with student 1, teacher 1 with student 4, and teacher 1 with student 5.  You then say "but only return the teacher info" but the basics of the query was about the _combination_ so you still get 3 results.

Answer (score 0):

You should create new table called hobby that has column id and name. So those tables should have column hobbyid that is foreign key, instead of having hobby name. Then when you do that, try this.

```
var query = select * from db.teacher t where t.hobbyid = (select s.hobbyid 
from db.student s)
```